# Apache Server Configuration Extension?

Tags: apache-http-server

I want to install a duplicate version of Apache server that shares almost all the configuration with an existing running version. Either one of the server will be running all the time and since I do not want to duplicate the configuration files, I referenced by httpd.conf file to include the httpd.conf of the original Apache server.

But I want to customize Virtual host setting in the ssl conf, more precisely the mod-rewrite rules, So I created httpd.ssl.conf file with all the changes. But since the original httpd.conf includes the original httpd.ssl.conf file, I am getting "Only one usage of socket address is permitted error ".

```
 MyHttpd.conf --> Includes Original Httpd.conf
                            --> Includes original httpdssl.conf

              --> Includes customizedHttpssl.conf
```

Is there a way to exclude the original httpssl.conf and make the system recognize my ssl.conf?  or may be extend the virtual host setting.

Answer (score 1):

Move everything but the include of the original SSL config out of `httpd.conf` into a new file called `httpdcommon.conf`.

Now setup

```
 httpd.conf --> Includes httpdcommon.conf
            --> Includes original httpdssl.conf
```

then

```
 MyHttpd.conf --> Includes httpdcommon.conf
              --> Includes customizedHttpssl.conf
```